# Azure Function - Cron Trigger - ok every second but not every minute

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a CRON for every minute in my Azure Function timer trigger.

As per the documentation I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-examples

`"0 */1 * * * *"` doesn't run at all.

`"*/1 * * * * *"` does run every second.

Where am I going wrong?

`function.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/TriggerWork/index.js"
}
```

Comment: How are you confirming it isn't running every minute? It looks correct is why I ask

Comment: Yep - I've waited for >1 minute. And the code is just the deafult sample as per the link above. I see it logging when I use `"*/1 * * * * *"`

Comment: Ah I just noticed in the console:
`The listener for function 'Functions.TriggerWork' was unable to start.
[4/17/19 4:09:22 AM] The listener for function 'Functions.TriggerWork' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Settings must be of the form "name=value".`

Comment: Looks like you don't configure the right storage key. You are testing on local or on the portal?

Comment: @GeorgeChen - sorry don't understand. Its running locally.

Comment: I'm assuming you were able to add a storage connection string and get it figured out?

Comment: Yep - that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with `{AzureWebJobsStorage}` connection string entry in the `local.settings.json` is somehow mismatched in its format:
[image]

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{AzureWebJobsStorage}",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

**For all triggers except for HTTP, a valid AzureWebJobsStorage connection string is required**. The reason behind this has to do with scaling out to multiple VMs: If the function scales out to multiple VMs and has multiple instances, a storage account is needed to coordinate to ensure that only one instance of the timer trigger is running at a time. This poses some difficulty if you are trying to develop locally but, unfortunately, this is currently a limitation of the timer trigger.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/224).

Comment: sorry, what is the solution in the end I did not get your answer? What kind of valid AzureWebJobsStorage should be?